# Reading ftp.exe console output continually, not by lines

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, ftp, command-prompt

I have a batch file that will perform an FTP download, and it does display all output during runtime if just clicked on, however, it doesn't display all the hashes (`####`) until after the download has finished when ran programmatically in Java. Is there a way for me to system print the # during the download? I assume the program is waiting for the full line to come in, so is there a way to get it in pieces?

Batch file:

```
echo user xxxxx>> ftpcmd.bat
echo xxxxx>> ftpcmd.bat
echo bin>> ftpcmd.bat
echo hash>> ftpcmd.bat
echo cd download>> ftpcmd.bat
echo get 01_MBytes.txt>> ftpcmd.bat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.bat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.bat xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx >> ftp_test.txt
del ftpcmd.bat
```

Java Code:

```
Process p = null;
InputStream processOutput;
BufferedReader reader = null;
String line = " ",output = " ";

p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c " + command);
processOutput = p.getInputStream();
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(processOutput));
while(line = reader.readLine()){
    System.out.println(line);
}
output += line + "\n";
```

Output During execution:

```
echo user xxxxx 1>>ftpcmd.bat 
echo xxxxx 1>>ftpcmd.bat 
echo bin 1>>ftpcmd.bat 
echo hash 1>>ftpcmd.bat 
echo cd download 1>>ftpcmd.bat 
echo get 01_MBytes.txt 1>>ftpcmd.bat 
echo quit 1>>ftpcmd.bat 
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.bat xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Hash mark printing On  ftp: (2048 bytes/hash mark) .
user LTETester 
bin
hash
cd download
get 01_MBytes.txt
```

Then after the download has finished (again, I am trying to see this as it happens):

```
#####################################################
#####################################################
#####################################################
#####################################################
#####################################################
quit
```

Comment: Why do you use `ftp.exe` for FTP transfer, instead of native Java solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading the output by lines. So naturally the `.readLine()` returns only after whole line is outputted by the `ftp.exe`, what is only after the transfer finishes.

You need to read the stream byte-wise, not line-wise. E.g. using the [`.read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read--):

```
public int read()
```

Answer (score -1):

This has nothing to do with batch files.

streams often have a `READ(numchar)` method as well as `readline` and `readall`. Basics and Window objects do anyway.